# Fluid Simulation looks white

Tags: materials, fluid-simulation

I'm using Cycles Render (Blender 2.79)
I created a domain, a circle that works as an inflow. I baked the simulation, the fluid looks like milk. I selected the domain, created a material (used glass for surface and volume absorption as volume). I render and I still see milk as my fluid, what's going on?

I have a sun, and I'm trying to simulate gasoline.

Here's My File: [image]

Answer (score 2):

You added a material to the domain, but it is currently not in use since it is not assigned to any part of the mesh.

This is however an easy fix; just remove the other material from the domain by selecting it (the one named "Material") and clicking the minus button on the right hand side. Your fluid should now be using the material "vino.004" instead.

[image]